# How do I find a specific String in an array of Objects, searching through each Object in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, object

I have set up an array of objects of various types (3 Objects, containing a String, Double, String, Double)

And I am looking to search for the first index in the array that returns "Specific String".

How do I do this in swift?
I have tried `.contains`, `.indexOf`, `.first`, and all of them keep giving me errors

The errors are:

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '(*myvalue*) throws -> Bool'
>   Cannot convert value of type '*Myobject*' to expected argument type ... 
>   etc.)

Any helpful ideas or information would be a blessing.

Comment: What code have you tried so far? and how are you defining that array? Do include all relevant code in your question

Comment: _"I have tried .contains, .indexOf, .first,"_ Show us what you have tried! We'll help you fix it.

Comment: "any helpful ideas or information would be a blessing" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose your objects are defined as follows:

```
struct MyObject {
    let firstString: String
    let firstDouble: Double
    let secondString: String
    let secondDouble: Double
}
```

Let's define three objects:

```
let firstObject = MyObject(firstString: "uno",
                           firstDouble: 1,
                           secondString: "un",
                           secondDouble: 11)
let secondObject = MyObject(firstString: "dos",
                           firstDouble: 2,
                           secondString: "deux",
                           secondDouble: 22)
let thirdObject = MyObject(firstString: "uno",
                           firstDouble: 3,
                           secondString: "deux",
                           secondDouble: 33)
```

And put them in an array:

```
let myArray: [MyObject] = [firstObject, secondObject, thirdObject]
```

You can get the first element that has their `firstString` property equal to `"uno"`, using [`first(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1848165-first):

```
let firstUno: (Int, MyObject)? = myArray
    .enumerated()
    .first(where: { $0.1.firstString == "uno"})

if let uno = firstUno {
    print("First uno index =", uno.0)  //First uno index = 0
    print("First uno object =", uno.1) //First uno object = MyObject(firstString: "uno", firstDouble: 1.0, secondString: "un", secondDouble: 11.0)
}
```

You could do the same to get the first object that has their `secondString` property equal to `"deux"`:

```
let firstDeux: (Int, MyObject)? = myArray
    .enumerated()
    .first(where: { $0.1.secondString == "deux"})

if let deux = firstDeux {
    print("First deux index =", deux.0)  //First deux index = 1
    print("First deux object =", deux.1) //First deux object = MyObject(firstString: "dos", firstDouble: 2.0, secondString: "deux", secondDouble: 22.0)
}
```

Comment: Thank you Carpsen90, this is exactly what I was looking for and it worked great.

Comment: @user8027140 Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for more information

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not advisable to have arrays of heterogeneous (multiple differing) types. They're generally pretty difficult to work with, and you've run into one of the pitfalls.

The variants of [`Collection.firstIndex(of:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/2995095-firstindex), [`Sequence.contains(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2904924-contains), etc. that you're looking for, are the ones that are conditionally defined  only when the element type is equatable. Even though all the types you mentioned are `Equatable`, the inferred type of the Array is `Array<Any>`. `Any` is not `Equatable`, thus your array is not a candidate for those functions.

Instead, you'll have to use the predicate based functions. They take a predicate, of type `(Element) -> Bool`. Each element is passed into the predicate as an argument to the parameter of type `Element`, and it's your job to return `true` if the element matches your predicate, and false if it does not. For example, [`index(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/2995097-firstindex) will return the index of the first element that makes your predicate return `true`. E.g:

```
let stuff: [Any] = [1, false, "abc"]
if let abcIndex = stuff.index(where: { $0 == "abc" }) {
    print("Found \"abc\" at index \(abcIndex)")
}
```

Unfortunately, `Equatable` is a protocol with an associated type. It's like a template which can describe types, but it isn't a nominal type in itself. Thus, you can't currently do anything like:

```
let equatableStuff: [Equatable] = [1, false, "abc"]
if let abcIndex = stuff.index(of: "abc") {
    print("Found \"abc\" at index \(abcIndex)")
}
```

Comment: This is used for a multi part array for an object that has a name, date of manufacture, manufacturer and cost.  Using what you have provided ends up giving me a: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '*myObject*' and 'String'